# Using foreach, Add Each Element to List Instead of Writing, Prolog

Tags: list, recursion, foreach, prolog

I currently have a database of facts that lists a symptom with a corresponding disease, shown below is a snippet

```
symptom(smallpox,fever).
symptom(smallpox,rash).
symptom(shingles,fever).
symptom(shingles,headache).
symptom(tetanus,hypertonia).
```

Part of my code using this line

```
findall(Disease,symptom(Disease,Symptom),Possibles)
```

I am able to make a list now for each disease possibility, however I need to create one list for each possibility for different symptoms entered. For example, currently if I enter "fever" and then "hypertonia", I get one list with "smallpox,shingles" and another list with "tetanus when it loops back through. How can I make a continuous list?

Comment: See: [Finding all Solutions to a Goal](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=allsolutions).

Comment: @GuyCoder thanks that worked! Is it possible to use the created list outside of the rule I created it in?

Comment: Yes, just pass it back.

Comment: If you know the answer to your own question, you should post it an accept it to get points for yourself.

Comment: @GuyCoder. You don't get points for accepting / upvoting your own answers to your own questions...

Comment: @repeat I know. Others will upvote it once they see that it is the accepted answer. :)